# DecimalFormat : replace floats with spaces

Tags: decimalformat

We need to display currency amounts in a browser table and since those are numbers, they should be right aligned.
Problem is with currencies like Japan which do not have floating point currencies.
So for them, we cannot show 5.10 Yen

Now, the requirement is to show something like this:
(Note the alignment and the mixing of decimal currencies with non-decimal)

```
  5.23
 12.00
  3.24
  5
  9
 11.00
```

In the above, 5 and 9 are Japanese Yens while others are USD
So the requirement is to replace floating points with spaces for currencies like JPY. Spaces are required to have proper alignment of the currencies.
Offcourse, for other currencies, the 2 decimal places should be there.

Does anyone know how the above can be done?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

---

### Based on the below replies:

1) The values are sent from a Java server and fed into a JavaScript library SlickGrid
2) We want to control values at the server level because the SlickGrid code is not very amenable for this kind of work.
3) Currencies are being stored as floats because customer wants to see them that way :( and that's kind of correct because mostly people are bothered about dollars not cents, but then, some people are concerned about cents too.

I was really hoping of some option with DecimalFormat only as that would have been the best solution.
Else I would have to resort to the ugly solution of parsing and string massaging.

Comment: I don't have the Javascript skills to offer a proper answer but would splitting all numbers into integer and decimal parts, printing the integer parts right aligned in one column and the decimal parts (unless disabled) left aligned in another do? Or do you e.g. need copy and paste to work properly?

Comment: Is the target font monospaced or proportional?

Comment: Why do you have different currencies in the same column?

Comment: Different currencies are in same column because our application provides user to manage his multi-currency accounts and so they need to see all transactions in one page.

Comment: Whenever it is possible to do something on the client or on the server, it is usually simpler to do it on the client - like, in 1001 out of 1000 cases. It is not hard to see why. On the client, you can "directly do something". Like, "make that red". On the server, if you want to make something red which is on the client's screen, you have to be indirect. Like, send a string (of HTML or JavaScript or CSS or whatever) which then sometime later (after that string traveled over the wire) causes something to be red. It is not even clear what you even mean by doing the formatting on the server.

Comment: (continued) DecimalFormat is Java, so that's on the server. And what do you want to do with that? Printing something on some screen attached to the server?? How is Java code supposed to help formatting *on the client*? You can only send a string (of HTML or JavaScript or something, not Java) to the client; and if you don't know how to configure slickgrid on the client, you don't know how to "do it from the server" either. It is evident you did not think this through. Really, just delete the second part of your question, it's going to be a much better question then.

Answer (score 3):

Currency should never be stored as a floating point number. It should always be integer amounts of the lowest denomination you are working with (Yen, Cents, Paise).

If you need to work with amounts smaller than the lowest natural denomination, store currency as integer amounts representing multiples of a specified fraction. For example 6 tenths of a Yen.

As for the formatting, there is a discussion of *simple* options [here](http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/javascript/table-align-char/).

Answer (score 0):

following CSS is basically taken from the link in jsj's answer (extracting the most relevant portion)

HTML only version:

```css
td { font-family: monospace; }
span.int {
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
  width: 3em;
}

span.fractional {
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td><span class="int">5</span><span class="fractional">.23</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="int">12</span><span class="fractional">.00</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="int">3</span><span class="fractional">.24</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="int">5</span><span class="fractional"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="int">9</span><span class="fractional"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="int">11</span><span class="fractional">.00</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript version:

```js
function spanInt(content){ var span = document.createElement('span');span.className = 'int'; span.textContent = content; return span; }
function spanFractional(content){ var span = document.createElement('span'); span.className = 'fractional'; span.textContent = content; return span;}
function tableCell_int(value){
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.appendChild(spanInt(value));
  td.appendChild(spanFractional(''));
  return td;
}
function tableCell_float(value){
  var intPart = Math.floor(value);
  var fracPart = value - intPart;
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.appendChild(spanInt(intPart));
  td.appendChild(spanFractional('.' + Math.round(100*fracPart)));
  return td;
}
function tr(cell){
  var elt = document.createElement('tr');
  elt.appendChild(cell);
  return elt;
}
var theTable = document.getElementById('theTable');
function add_int(value){ theTable.appendChild(tr(tableCell_int(value))); }
function add_float(value){ theTable.appendChild(tr(tableCell_float(value))); }

add_float(5.23); add_float(12); add_float(3.24);
add_int(5); add_int(9); add_float(11);
```

```css
td { font-family: monospace; }
span.int {
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
  width: 3em;
}

span.fractional {
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table id='theTable'></table>
```